# how to replace a double quote with string ' \" ' in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML in which the double quotes should be replaced with the string \".

eg:`<root><statement1><![CDATA[<u>teset "message"here</u>]]></statement1></root>`

so the output should be `<root><statement1><![CDATA[<u>teset \"message\"here</u>]]></statement1></root>`

Can anybody explain how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"
 cdata-section-elements="statement1"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pPattern">"</xsl:param>
 <xsl:param name="pReplacement">\"</xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="statement1/text()" name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pPat" select="$pPattern"/>
  <xsl:param name="pRep" select="$pReplacement"/>

 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, $pPat))">
   <xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($pText, $pPat)"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$pRep"/>
   <xsl:call-template name="replace">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
         "substring-after($pText, $pPat)"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pPat" select="$pPat"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pRep" select="$pRep"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <statement1><![CDATA[<u>teset "message"here</u>]]></statement1>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <statement1><![CDATA[<u>teset \"message\"here</u>]]></statement1>
</root>
```

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"
 cdata-section-elements="statement1"/>

 <xsl:param name="pPat">"</xsl:param>
 <xsl:param name="pRep">\\"</xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="statement1/text()">
   <xsl:sequence select="replace(.,$pPat, $pRep)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document (as above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
      <statement1><![CDATA[<u>teset \"message\"here</u>]]></statement1>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version='1.0'   ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                version='1.0'>
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//p">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(text(), '&amp;x22;','#')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It worked for me ....

Comment: The problem is that the replacement string is two characters long.

Comment: What you see, is the escape sequence for quote - then I used the hash mark. This will illustrate - that you can do this - even mixing escape sequence with symbols :)

Comment: As I said, the problem is that the replacement string is two characters long. It’s `\"`, not `#`.